# ¿Qué significa "curtido a pie de calle"?

Tags: expresiones

Empiecé a leer [esta entrevista](http://elpais.com/elpais/2013/10/18/eps/1382107992_999726.html) y encontré esa expressión, "curtido a pie de calle":

> este gobernante de raza, *curtido a pie de calle* y en la lucha sindical

¿Qué significa? Sé lo que significa *literalmente* pero no entiendo el significado connotativo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Por un lado, según la RAE:

> **[Curtir](http://dle.rae.es/curtir)**
> *Acostumbrar a alguien a la vida dura y a sufrir adversidades
> que puedan sobrellevarse con el paso del tiempo.*
>
>     **estar curtido en** algo: *Estar acostumbrado a ello o diestro en hacerlo.*
>
> **[Curtido](http://dle.rae.es/curtido)**
> *Coloquialmente, experimentado.*

Por otro lado, la expresión **`a pie de calle`** tiene un significado bastante literal, es decir, significa simplemente **`en la calle`**, pero con un poco más de énfasis, recalcando que es **`en la misma/propia calle`**, **`al nivel de la calle`**... Puedes ver la traducción y varios hilos al respecto en [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=a%20pie%20de%20calle).

---

Por lo tanto, la frase **`curtido a pie de calle`** en ese contexto básicamente se refiere a que el gobernante tiene **una gran experiencia**, que ha adquirido a base de participar en **protestas** de carácter social y **manifestaciones** populares, las cuales por supuesto tienen lugar **en las calles**...

---

Yo creo que el autor quiere reflejar que no se trata del típico personaje político que trabaja siempre encerrado en su oficina rodeado de papeleo y en contacto únicamente con otros miembros de la clase política. Para hablar de un político así, el autor probablemente hubiese escrito algo como: **`con una extensa carrera en los despachos`**...

Por el contrario, el autor usa la frase **`curtido a pie de calle`** para recalcar que se trata de una persona que ha tenido que seguir un camino difícil y que ha estado involucrado en los problemas sociales y en contacto con el pueblo en todo momento, luchando como un ciudadano más...

---

**EDIT**: Prestad atención a la puntualización que hace @MikMik en su comentario más abajo, que es muy interesante...

Comment: No estoy seguro de llamar **bastante literal** a la expresión `a pie de calle`.  Por lo demás me parece una muy buena explicación.  Bastante clara.

Comment: Recuerdo haber leído, creo que en [El Dardo en la Palabra](http://www.amazon.es/DARDO-EN-LA-PALABRA-EL/dp/B00FGSR23E) que las expresiones `a pie de calle`, `a pie de campo`, etc. son _incorrectas_, derivadas de `a pie de obra` o `a pie de fábrica`, que sí están aceptadas (aunque lo correcto o incorrecto depende del uso, con lo cual probablemente terminen siendo _correctas_).

Comment: @MikMik, good point! La verdad que a mí me suena absolutamente correcto y muy común, pero puede que tengas razón, porque si buscas **pie** en a RAE, vienen muchísimas *frases hechas* con la palabra pie, entre ellas **a pie de obra** e incluso **a pie de fábrica**, sin embargo no viene **a pie de calle**...

Answer (score 2):

Parece la típica expresión de lenguaje periodístico. Significa que ha adquirido mucha experiencia en algo no a través de la teoría sino mediante la práctica en la calle.